# Cannot sort a date array into Descending in Lotusscript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, notesview

Seeking for your help. I'm trying to sort a Date array to descending order but to no avail.

Here is the snippet of my code:

`Dim sortValue as Variant`

`Dim sortValueResult as Variant`

`Dim r1 as String`

`SortValue = entry.Columnvalues(1)`

`' The values are (0) 19/5/2018 and (1) 26/5/2018`

`r1 = Join(sortValue, ";")`

`sortValueResult = Evaluate ( {@Sort("} & r1 & {";[DESCENDING])})`
`

I'm getting 19/5/2018;26/5/2018

26/5/2018 must come first before 19/5/2018.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`@Sort` can work on date lists, but you are not passing in a list. You are passing in a string.

In Notes formula language syntax, a list is represented by elements separated by ":" characters; the string representation with ";" characters is not actually a list. You can go back and forth between string and list formats with `@Explode` and `@Implode`, but the output of `@Explode` is always a text list, not a date list. You could deal with that with `@TextToTime`, but you really might as well just avoid that by directly creating list notation. You need to surround each data string with brackets to turn it into a date constant, and separate them with colon characters - putting them all within a LotusScript string.

Something like this (*not tested*) should get it into proper list notation before you make your Evaluate call:

```
forall r in r1
  r = "[" + r + "]"         ' [19/5/2018] is proper date constant notation
end forall
r1 = Join(sortValue, ":")   ' colon is list separator
' result here should be r1 = "[9/5/2018] : [26/5/2018]"
```

Comment: Or you could do `r1 = "[" + Join(sortValue, "] : [") + "]"`